# Dynamic text in textarea - getting value

Tags: javascript, jquery

My text/value in textarea it's not static - I'm chaning it. I can't get the current value.
E.g
1

```
<textarea>
Lorem ipsum
</textarea>
//it's defalut in html file
```

2

> ```
> Putting into textarea:
>
> Dolores is lorem ipsum
> ```

Alert is only showing 1 version("lorem ipsum"), but not second ("Dolores is lorem ipsum"). I'm trying to do it in jquery:

```
var variable = $("#selector").val();
alert(variable);
```

What I'm doing wrong?

## EDIT

I want to catch it to variable :) Not to alert. Alert is only my test :)

Comment: It seems you are not setting the value of the textarea to the new content. Where is the code for that?

Comment: Wait, you're changing it by entering text? Or with JavaScript?

Comment: there is some formatting error in #2 can you pleas edit your post in order to make your actual html code appear correctly?

Comment: I'm changing textarea - I need to get value/text when I want to. Then I need to pass it to variable.

Comment: So you can see the changed text in the textarea? Then you are trying to access the value at the wrong time.

Comment: @FelixKling What do you mean? I do it when i do an action(by yourself).

Comment: Ahh... now I understand.... you are typing the text into the text area, is that right? It sounded like you are changing it programatically. That was not clear to be honest. And then, after you typed the text, how do you trigger the alert?

Comment: I'm using tabs ui and alert is running when i change a tab(using select: ). In select: is the same code (jQuery) as i write in my first psot.

Comment: You should provide that code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var text = $('#textareaID').val();

$('#textareaID').change(function() {
  text = $(this).val();
});
```

when ever you want text just reference it :)

EDIT:

If your using tabs UI please review the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) and the event management:

```
Place This outside of bound scope:
var text = $('#textareaID').val(); OR var text = '';

$('#example').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
      // Objects available in the function context:
      // ui.tab anchor element of the selected (clicked) tab
      // ui.panel element, that contains the selected/clicked tab contents
      // ui.index zero-based index of the selected (clicked) tab
      // INSIDE HERE IS WHERE YOU CAN PUT THE CODE IN THE ABOVE EXAMPLE
      $('#textareaID').change(function() {
            text = $(this).val();
      });
});
```

NOTE: $('#example') would be the parent div that holds the tabs and content

Further optimization recommendation.

If you think  $('#textareaID') will be called often you may want to cache a reference to it so the selector engine does not have to find it on every instance, this would be done like:

```
var textarea = $('#textareaID');
 var text = $('#textareaID').val();
```

For this line:

```
var textarea = $('#textareaID');
```

Make sure it is inside of a $(document).ready(function() {}); Call and the element is exists

you could check for this by doing:

```
var textarea = $('#textareaID') || false;
```

And wrap the code above like this:

```
$('#example').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
          // Objects available in the function context:
          // ui.tab anchor element of the selected (clicked) tab
          // ui.panel element, that contains the selected/clicked tab contents
          // ui.index zero-based index of the selected (clicked) tab
          // INSIDE HERE IS WHERE YOU CAN PUT THE CODE IN THE ABOVE EXAMPLE

          if(textarea) {
               textarea.change(function() {
                    text = $(this).val();
               });
          }
    });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm using tabs ui and alert is running when i change a tab(using select: ). In select: is the same code (jQuery) as i write in my first psot. When i'm clicking my tabs, it's always the same value as default :)

Comment: CODE IS MESSY IN COMMENT SEE EDIT ABOVE: If your using tabs UI look into the events that it will fire and when they get fired. http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

$('#example').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {

    // Objects available in the function context:
    ui.tab     // anchor element of the selected (clicked) tab
    ui.panel   // element, that contains the selected/clicked tab contents
    ui.index   // zero-based index of the selected (clicked) tab
    // INSIDE HERE IS WHERE YOU CAN PUT THE CODE IN THE ABOVE EXAMPLE
});

Answer (score 1):

```
$('textarea').change(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to tie the `alert()` to an event:

```
$('textarea').change(
    function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/errnr/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

Answer (score 1):

#### The error is somewhere else.

The code you are using is correct. Check a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/JAsTb/)

Comment: Yes. But try to do catch an text/value from textarea when is changed. This code doesn't works for me when i need to get a current text.

Comment: @GabrielŻukowski, can't you get the alert of a new value on my demo? Get it on a varible on the same way.

Comment: @GabrielŻukowski, can you duplicate your problem on same demo?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to assign the `.val()` to a variable before the value changes.  You are correct in that you want to use `.val()`.  Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcond/ts8sS/1/) to see the differences that are produced by the `variable`, `.val()`, `.text()`, and `.html()`.

Comment: I'm using tabs ui and alert is running when i change a tab(using select: ). In select: is the same code (jQuery) as i write in my first psot. When i'm clicking my tabs, it's always the same value as default :)

Comment: So the textarea is on the tab you're going TO or the tab you're coming FROM?  If it's on the tab you're going TO, then it sounds like you're storing the value BEFORE it changes, which makes sense.  Please clarify.